# How to port fork() to Vxwork

Tags: c, linux, porting, embedded-linux, vxworks

i am porting program from GNU/Linux to VxWorks, i am having a problem regarding to `fork()` and i can't find alternatives ; VxWork's API provide two useful calls `taskSpawn( )` and `rtpSpawn( )` to spwan RTP/Task but these API do NOT duplicate the calling process (fork does). does anyone have idea about porting/workaround fork() to Vxworks?

[VxWorks API Reference](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/rtnIndex.htm)

Comment: I would try hard to avoid using `fork` and use VxWorks primitives. This may require to re-design part of the program.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i am porting that +9000 program that already written for GNU/Linux, so i am looking for solution so i dont need to re-design the program :)

Comment: You might not find such solutions. Perhaps only a few hundred lines are depending upon `fork`, and you have to identify, redesign and recode these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember my vxWork correctly - you can't. fork() requires virtual memory management, something I believe VxWorks 5.5 does not provide, at least not the full semantics needed to implement fork. (it was added in vxwork 6 though if I am not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about VxWorks memory model but it may be impossible to port fork. The reason for this is that when a process is forked, the memory of the original process is copied into the new process. Importantly, the two processes must use the same internal virtual addresses otherwise things like pointers are going to break.

Obviously, the two processes must have different physical addresses which means in order to fork, one requires a platform that has a memory management unit (MMU) and the kernel must support a memory model that allows programs to share the same virtual addresses. This is why there is no fork equivalent for creating a new thread.

In addition to this, copying a large process can be very expensive. So Linux uses what is called copy-on-write. This means all fork does is mark all memory pages read-only. When a write is attempted, an interrupt is generated and only then is the memory page copied.

It is unlikely that a Real Time Operating System RTOS will support copy-on-write because it means that memory write times are not bounded and violates the realtime guarantees of the OS.

It is therefore much easier not to support fork at all just implement APIs for spawning brand new processes without the duplication.

Comment: SymbianOS never supported fork even though it had a posix compatible library for this very reason